# Prestashop 1.6 custom module : addJS/addCSS don't work properly

Tags: php, module, hook, prestashop-1.6

I created my prestashop module, with a hook to display my specific search form.

```
public function hookDisplayTopColumn($params)
{

    $this->context->controller->addCSS($this->_path.'css/modelfilter.css', 'all');
    $this->context->controller->addJS($this->_path.'js/modelfilter.js');


    $marque = $this->getSubCategories($this->marquesCategory);

    $this->context->smarty->assign(array(
        'marques' => $marque,
    ));
    return $this->display(__FILE__, 'form_model.tpl');
}
```

JS and CSS files are not included. To find why, I added a parse line in *classes/controller/FrontController.php* :

```
public function addMedia($media_uri, $css_media_type = null, $offset = null, $remove = false, $check_path = true)
{
    echo 'addMedia '.$media_uri."<br/>\n";
```

And the result is : all css/js files appears before the beginning of the page (just after `<body>`), but my files comes just before displaying form_model.tpl

Please, how to make my files to be called in the good time ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You shall not use `$this->context->controller->addCSS` and `addJS` outside of `hookDisplayHeader()`.

When the header of your page is built `hookDisplayHeader()` is called to add headers elements. Once this hook is done, the header is built and can't be changed.

So when the hook `hookDisplayTopColumn()` is called, the header is already built.

To add your files you have to implement the `hookDisplayHeader()` in your module:

```
public function hookDisplayHeader($params)
{
    $this->context->controller->addCSS($this->_path.'css/modelfilter.css', 'all');
    $this->context->controller->addJS($this->_path.'js/modelfilter.js');
}
```

And remove those lines from `hookDisplayTopColumn()`.

Comment: OK, thanks. Looks I was not awake enough this morning. Now it seems so obvious ...

Comment: If this answer solved your issue can you please accept it? [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)